# Simple pattern search across 'select' with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to make a simple search across select box with single selection.
Main idea is to select first option element that matches simple pattern.

Simple pattern: it can contain `*` or `?` placeholders which means any symbols.

How can i make this script with jQuery ?
Using Regexp ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extend your jQuery with [this little snippet](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

..you can use selectors like this:

```
# to match child elements of #container which have their
# value attribute in the form of /.*names?/
$("#container option:regex(value, .*names?)")
```